# swagger configuration in eureka for all microservices registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, microservices

In my use case, I want to apply swagger in my application. I am able to configuration swagger for one micro-services. But suppose I have many micro-services which are registered in eureka server. I want to configure swagger in eureka such a way that, it will fetch all the micro-services' endpoint and make it available in swagger-ui.

So that I don't need to configure all the micro-services, just configure it in eureka and it should work.

Comment: Eureka is just a registration server. How can you have access to all the swagger specifications from each micro service if they don't expose it? Eureka knows nothing about what each service does.

Comment: I don't want access all micro-services' swagger specifications in eureka. I want to create one application in which I can configure swagger which can fetch all microservices info from eureka and then make it available on swagger.

Comment: Do you want to deploy one swagger-ui, or one spec (i.e. swagger yaml)?

For one swagger-ui with multiple specs included, one way is to expose the spec from each microservice as a http resource, for example with springfox. Then your aggregator service (e.g. API gateway) can discover the services, query the predefined endpoints and add them to the UI. (I have done this, but it required a little rewrite for the swagger-ui). However, it will not work if you don't want to 'configure all the micro-services'.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late.. But, if anyone have this question, here is the solution:
You can't fetch all microservices api docs from Eureka, you have to put the swagger config in the Gateway (in my case, zuul gateway)!
So u basically have to put swagger in all microservices and in the zuul, follow the steps in this site "https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/microservices-api-documentation-with-swagger2/" and be happy xD

Comment: Updated to v3: https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/

Answer (score 0):

it is not eureka role , each microservice is a individual application.